# What does Hana's middle initial stand for?

Tags: hanayamata

In Hanayamata, Hana's full name is "Hana N. Fountainstand" (or Fontaine-Stand, or Fonteyn-Stand, or Founteyne-Stand, depending on who you talk to). Do we ever find out what "N" stands for?

I'm pretty sure this never happened in the anime, so I'm expecting it was revealed in the manga if it ever was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be revealed anywhere officially, but based on fans' theory:
**The "N" should be a word <sup>(that has similar pronunciation with)</sup> "Now"**.

Japanese fans found that all* characters in Hanayamata are related to Kamakura city in Kanagawa Prefecture, Japan.

From [an anon user id 900RcZoqa on post no. 960 on 2channel](http://raptor.2ch.net/test/read.cgi/livejupiter/1475301406/l50),

> 全部地名
>
> 『ハナヤマタ』
>   関谷なる → 鎌倉市関谷
>   笹目ヤヤ → 鎌倉市笹目
>   常盤マチ → 鎌倉市常盤
>   西御門多美 → 鎌倉市西御門
>
> ---
>
> All of them are name of places
>
> "Hanayamata"
>   Naru Sekiya → Kamakura city, Sekiya
>   Yaya Sasame → Kamakura city, Sasame
>   Machi Tokiwa → Kamakura city, Tokiwa
>   Tami Nishimikado → Kamakura city, Nishimikado

that leaves Hana N. Fountainstand.

Turns out there's also a place in Kamakura city called Imaizumidai. Imaizumidai in Japanese is 今泉台. If each character is translated to English,

- 今 = **N**ow
- 泉 = **Fountain**
- 台 = **Stand**

they match with "N. Fountainstand".

> ハナ・N・フォンテーンスタンド → 鎌倉市今泉台（Now→今 fountain→泉 stand→台）

As for what does the "N" stand for, we can't really know, since as it's been mentioned, フォンテーンスタンド might be read as *Fountainstand*, *Fontaine-Stand*, *Fonteyn-Stand*, *Founteyne-Stand*, etc. Thus, the "N" might be *Now*, *Nau*, *Naw*, etc.

---

*Except Sachiko Yamanoshita. There's no Yama-no-shita in Kamakura city, but there's **Yama**-no-uchi and Saka-no-**shita**. (From [Japanese Yahoo! Answers](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11135749451))

Also, there's someone who travelled around Kamakura to find these places. ([1](http://imatre.exblog.jp/22635076/), [2](http://imatre.exblog.jp/22906649/))

Comment: Wow, after two years I'd given up on this ever getting an answer, and here it finally is. Good job and +1.